# <select> menu opened cursor IE11

Tags: css, html, combobox, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with IE11 and  menu.

When opened the combo, the cursor changes depending on the input behind.

```
<div>
  <select>
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" value="mouse changes" readonly="readonly" /> 
</div>
```

When trying in IE11, the cursor changes in option 2, to the readonly, it select the option if clicking but it seems forbidden option.